# getting connected user informations using firebase, getUID gives the wrong ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[][1]I am using firebase for my android studio project. I need to add a child under the parent "food" each time a user sends some information by clicking a button. and that child has the user's id (the user that is connected and clicked that button) and the name of that user as children.
I wrote this code to set the value of the child "donor id" to the id of the wanted user:

```
    FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = 
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
    myRef.child(foodID).child("donor id")
                       .setValue(currentFirebaseUser.getUid());
```

However the value of the added ID is wrong and doesn't even correspond to any user. what is the problem ? and how can I add other children of that user like his name to be a child of the foodID?
as requested, I added  a screenshot of the database :

[image]

Comment: Why do yo usay that `currentFirebaseUser.getUid()` returns a wrong id? How did checked that?

Comment: I looked for the id of the connected user in my database and it is a completely different ID , and I even checked if the returned ID correspond to any registered user but it did not, it is a completely random value.

Comment: Please show us some examples. Some printscreens can help us.

Comment: @AlexMamo Depends on what printscreen you're looking for. Screenshots of the database? Or screenshots of code (which shouldn't be done due to readability, hard for screen readers/no accessibility, etc.)?

Comment: Every screenshot that can help us solve the issue.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the database, I hope this helps find the problem.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` would be anything but the current user's UID. What makes you say that it's the wrong value?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it is returning the id of the user in the authentification section which is not the same as the one in the database. Sorry I thought the id in authentification and in firebase were the same.